# How to dismiss phonegap notification alert automatically on app minimise

Tags: cordova

I want to close the phonegap notification alert when I minimise my application 
So there will not be any click from the user to manually cancel the alert rather it should be cancelled/minimised/dismissed automatically
Is there a way out ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the pause event, right?

Comment: If I put in a pause event, on resume the alert is still displayed.

Comment: I didn't mean to *just* use a pause event, but to close the alert in the pause event. :)

Comment: So I just checked - and from what I see - you can't programatically dismiss dialogs. Therefore you would need to write your *own* UI to do a dialog so you can clear it yourself.

Comment: Thanks Raymond, I'm aware of that, still wanna know if there is any minute possiblity

Comment: Not based on my Googling. Not saying 100% for sure, but it seems to be the consensus.